# Governor Limits: Scheduled Flows vs Async Apex

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, asynchronous, scheduled-job, asyncapexjob

**tl;dr** - Do schedule flows (flow builder, not process builder) count against the same limit of scheduleable jobs that asynch apex (Queueable, Scheduleable, Batch) is limited by? If not, in what way to they differ?

**Background**

Our org is running into issues with hitting the maximum number of async apex jobs. We are looking into using scheduled flows as a means of bypassing some of these limits (while also looking into optimizing root issues).

**Question**

Do schedule jobs sent from flows in the flow builder (not the process builder) count against the same limits that scheduled (and other async) apex jobs must adhere to? If not, in what ways are the limits different, and is there any interaction between the two?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_trigger_schedule.htm&type=5